# Menu dividers in ncurses

Tags: c, ruby, ncurses

I'd like to build a menu in ncurses that has section dividers.

My example list looks like this:

```
Aardvark
Apple
Bee
Cat
Kitten
Kalashnikov
Waffle
```

What I want is non-selectable dividers. Something like this:

```
(A) ----
Aardvark
Apple
(B) ----
Bee
(C) ----
Cat
(K) ----
Kitten
Kalashnikov
(W) ----
Waffle
```

Is there a built-in way to do this?

More specifically, I'm using this ruby gem: https://github.com/eclubb/ncurses-ruby I'd prefer an answer that was generic, but if it can be solved with Ruby awesomeness, that's cool too.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449492/ncurses-how-to-refresh-a-menu-without-losing-current-position/34453114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the ncurses [`menu`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/menu.3x.html) library (as "built-in"), you can make a nonselectable item using [`set_item_opts`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/mitem_opts.3x.html).

Comment: Perfect again! Caught this question and my other (somewhat related) one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449492/ncurses-how-to-refresh-a-menu-without-losing-current-position/34453114#34453114

Comment: After having experimented with this a bit, it looks like I can still move over the item with the cursor, even though it's not "selectable". Is there a built-in way of having these items be skipped by the menu_driver REQ_<UP/DOWN>_ITEM method?

Comment: You would do this in the driver callbacks (the driver only delivers events, which the callbacks can interpret as needed).

Comment: Thanks - that works for me. I ended up just calling `REQ_<UP/DOWN>_ITEM` again whenever the current item's `user_object` was nil. (Plus a bit of other logic to handle the first item in the list.)